# Status of MouseButton for DrawingArea

Tags: c#, multithreading, gtk#

I want to drawing image in the DrawingArea by mouse. I can know current mouse coordinate in the DrawingArea, but how can I know what's mouse button pressed? My current code looks like:

```
            protected void OnPaintedPicture1DrawingareaMotionNotifyEvent (object o, MotionNotifyEventArgs args)
            {
                EventMotion currentEventMotion = (args.Args[0] as EventMotion);

                matchingPercentageForPicture1AndSample1_entry.Text+=String.Format("x='{0}'; y='{1}';\t", currentEventMotion.X, currentEventMotion.Y);
            }
```

Comment: I think its the lParam variable that you can normally use for mouse states but not got any evidence yet to back this up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the information about mouse buttons (and modifer keys) from `currentEventMotion.State`. It contains a value of [`Gdk.ModifierType`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGdk.ModifierType).

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get MotionNotifyEvent when user press mouse button. Can you tell me how to generate MotionNotifyEvent when button pressed? Now I change my code by the next way:     EventMotion currentEventMotion = (args.Args[0] as EventMotion);
    
    //third bit - does Ctrl pressed
    if((Convert.ToInt32(currentEventMotion.State) & Convert.ToInt32("000000100",2))!=0)
    {
     matchingPercentageForPicture1AndSample1_entry.Text+=String.Format("x='{0}'; y='{1}';\t", currentEventMotion.X, currentEventMotion.Y);
    }

Comment: Your question seemed to be about getting the button state from a motion notify event. If you want to get an event when a button is pressed, connect to `ButtonPressEvent` or `ButtonReleaseEvent` signals.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
  switch(LOWORD(wp))
   {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
```

following on from my comment I found this.. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/400920/Handling-WM_LBUTTONUP-WM_LBUTTONDOWN-Messages-for

Comment: I doesn't coding by C++, I use C# for my program